# How to restrict access to LAMP for certain IP ranges

Tags: iptables, apache-httpd, postfix

I want to restrict all access to Apache and Postfix to a certain geographical region; how can I do this?

If I want to do this, is it best to use iptables or should I do it per application? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Why do you want to limit your site to certain locations?  Clarifying that will help giving proper advice.

Comment: Because it is only meant for a certain geographical region.

Comment: That is quite unusual.  Some sites will customize the view depending on the location but to only be available in certain regions will cause you serious issues with search engines.

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult and possible only with severe limitations.  Geographical information of internet users is usually not available.  The closest one gets is to look up their IP in a geo-ip database.  Such free databases only give a coarse classification (country); everything else is possibly quite expensive.

What's more is that: IP addresses can be spoofed, cell phone users are often "located" in regions very remote from their actual position, and VPNs and similar services allow users to hide their real IP address, fooling any IP-based location methods.

Long story short: Unless you have very good reasons to do so and know what you are doing, I'd **advise against doing this**.

If you *must* implement such a thing (don't!), `iptables` would be a good option.  Just look for a basic tutorial or read the man page (focus on the `-s` option for matching).

Comment: Limitation using country or geographical region (continent) is quite sufficient.

Comment: Well, if it's really what you need, go for it then. Search for *geoip* and you'll find plenty of services and programs.  Some are bundled with some linux distros.  But, with the risk of repeating myself: It won't keep anybody out if they really want to get to your site, while possibly locking legitimate users out.